# netmeeting activex control wb32.exe embed

Tags: windows, activex

I have been looking at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms708704(v=vs.85).aspx

with no help.  I was wondering if it were possible to invoke wb32.exe (Whiteboard application for netmeeting) through html (without using a "shell").

Thanks,
df

Comment: You cannot start an EXE from a web page.  Click the pad+pen icon.

Comment: LOL. I'm upvoting because I worked on Netmeeting too many years ago.  NetMeeting hasn't shipped anything new since 1999 and is unfortunately not supported much anymore. You could in fact launch NetMeeting through the ActiveX control back in the day. I suspect that CLSID is blacklisted on IE now. But you can't get NetMeeting on any OS newer than XP.

Comment: But hey, you might be able to resurrect something with the NM 3.0 resoruce kit. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21405  But honestly, there's so many good online whiteboard services out there today. Including Lync Online and Google Docs, you'll be better off looking into those services.